Property of a class using MQTT does not return the correct value?
I have developed a class using MQTT to get the value of a topic.
Below is the complete code:
using MQTTnet;
using MQTTnet.Client;
using MQTTnet.Server;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ClassMQTTTest
{
   public class ClassMQTT
    {
        private string broker;
        private int brokerPort;
        private string topic;
        private string clientId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        private MqttFactory factory;
        private MQTTnet.Client.MqttClient mqttClient;
        private MQTTnet.Client.MqttClientOptions conexOptions;
        private MQTTnet.Client.MqttClientConnectResult connectToMQTT;
        public string topicValue;

        //Constructor
        public ClassMQTT(string broker, int brokerPort, string topic)
        {
            this.broker = broker;
            this.brokerPort = brokerPort;
            this.topic = topic;

            factory = new MqttFactory();
            mqttClient = (MQTTnet.Client.MqttClient)factory.CreateMqttClient();
            conexOptions = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
                .WithTcpServer(this.broker, this.brokerPort)
                .WithCredentials("", "")
                .WithClientId(clientId)
                .WithCleanSession()
                .Build();
        }

        private async Task procConnectToMQTT()
        {
            connectToMQTT = await mqttClient.ConnectAsync(this.conexOptions);
        }

        private bool isConnectedToMQTT()
        {
            return (connectToMQTT.ResultCode == MqttClientConnectResultCode.Success);
        }

        public async Task getTopicValue()
        {
            await procConnectToMQTT();

            if (isConnectedToMQTT())
            {
                await mqttClient.SubscribeAsync(topic);                
                //Callback function when anything is publish on the topic
                mqttClient.ApplicationMessageReceivedAsync += e =>
                {
                    topicValue = e.ApplicationMessage.ConvertPayloadToString();
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };
            }
        }
    }
}

After, on a event button of a form, i have the follow code:
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClassMQTTTest testMQTT = new ClassMQTTTest("xxxxxx", 000000, "topicTest");
    await testMQTT.getTopicValue();
    string vTopic = testMQTT.topicValue;
    MessageBox.Show(vTopic);    
}

Call to MessageBox show a empty string. But, debbuging the getTopicValue() method, topicValue is assigned correctly with a value
subscribe of a topic.
The assign on "string vTopic = testMQTT.topicValue;" returns a NULL !!!
How to get a vTopic assign in getTopicValue()???
Thank's in advance

The issue you are facing is related to asynchronous programming in C#. The assignment of the topicValue happens inside an asynchronous event (ApplicationMessageReceivedAsync). The problem is that the assignment of topicValue may not have been completed by the time you check its value in the line string vTopic = testMQTT.topicValue.
The MessageBox.Show(vTopic) call is executed immediately after await testMQTT.getTopicValue();, but the message from the MQTT broker might not have been received yet. To resolve this, you can modify your code to wait for the message reception, or add a more robust mechanism to notify the main thread when the value has been received.
Here's an improved approach using a TaskCompletionSource to wait for the message reception:
Updated ClassMQTT:
using MQTTnet;
using MQTTnet.Client;
using MQTTnet.Server;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ClassMQTTTest
{
   public class ClassMQTT
    {
        private string broker;
        private int brokerPort;
        private string topic;
        private string clientId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        private MqttFactory factory;
        private MQTTnet.Client.MqttClient mqttClient;
        private MQTTnet.Client.MqttClientOptions conexOptions;
        private MQTTnet.Client.MqttClientConnectResult connectToMQTT;
        private TaskCompletionSource<string> topicValueTaskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

        //Constructor
        public ClassMQTT(string broker, int brokerPort, string topic)
        {
            this.broker = broker;
            this.brokerPort = brokerPort;
            this.topic = topic;

            factory = new MqttFactory();
            mqttClient = (MQTTnet.Client.MqttClient)factory.CreateMqttClient();
            conexOptions = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
                .WithTcpServer(this.broker, this.brokerPort)
                .WithCredentials("", "")
                .WithClientId(clientId)
                .WithCleanSession()
                .Build();
        }

        private async Task procConnectToMQTT()
        {
            connectToMQTT = await mqttClient.ConnectAsync(this.conexOptions);
        }

        private bool isConnectedToMQTT()
        {
            return (connectToMQTT.ResultCode == MqttClientConnectResultCode.Success);
        }

        public async Task<string> getTopicValueAsync()
        {
            await procConnectToMQTT();

            if (isConnectedToMQTT())
            {
                await mqttClient.SubscribeAsync(topic);

                //Callback function when anything is published on the topic
                mqttClient.ApplicationMessageReceivedAsync += e =>
                {
                    var message = e.ApplicationMessage.ConvertPayloadToString();
                    topicValueTaskSource.TrySetResult(message); // Set the result when the message is received
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };

                // Wait for the message reception
                return await topicValueTaskSource.Task;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}

Updated Event Handler:
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClassMQTT testMQTT = new ClassMQTT("xxxxxx", 000000, "topicTest");
    string vTopic = await testMQTT.getTopicValueAsync();
    MessageBox.Show(vTopic ?? "No value received");
}

Explanation:

TaskCompletionSource: This helps to create a task that completes only when a result is available, i.e., when the message from the MQTT broker is received.
await on the TaskCompletionSource: The await ensures that the message reception is awaited and the code after it is only executed once the message has been received.

Now, the MessageBox.Show(vTopic) will display the correct value once it's available from the MQTT broker.

Thank you Saurabh Sharma. Very very thanks.
